# Put slash in Angular Menu Items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

How i can add slash in angular menu items? It doesn't work in the url since it outputs some characters and not the slash. The food/fruits doesnt work. Here's my code below

```
{
    state: 'food/fruits',
    name: 'Fruits',
    type: 'link',
},
```

Comment: menu items? can you please add your html so we can better understand your question?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon. I dont need to add html. I just need to fix the state. Isnt it possible to put backslash there?

Comment: then i doubt you will get much help if you dont provide more information

Comment: @Joseph are you talking about AngularJS or Angular? I'm not aware of the concept of "state" in Angular.

Comment: sry but what you provided in the example is a regular slash (ASCII 47), not a backslash(ASCII 92) - might wanna edit your question..

Comment: @iLuvLogix its a slash sorry i just edited it

Comment: @Joseph do you have time to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML code `&#47;` for your slash.

[Here](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) is a complete list of the special ASCII characters.